# Линия огибающая объекты 2D

Tags: алгоритм

**Задача**: на входе есть 2 точки, а точнее их координаты X и У. Также есть объекты, которые представляют из себя прямоугольники, координаты вершин, а соответственно и их стороны известны. Необходимо организовать алгоритм, чтобы это линия огибала объекты. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет где посмотреть, или в каком направлении лучше двигаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас 5 отрезков. Первым шагом - искать пересечение исходного отрезка с отрезками сторон прямоугольника (объекта). [Реализация проверки на пересечение](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segments_intersection_checking). Либо гугл, реализаций навалом. Затем просто придумать, как добавить точку относительно точки, где соединяются отрезки сторон, которые пересекает исходный отрезок, чтобы линия огибала объект через 2 отрезка.

Comment: Посмотрите алгоритмы нахождения выпуклой оболочки (например [алгоритм Грэхема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Грэхема)). Это не совсем то, что надо, но довольно близко - хорошая возможность получить идеи для разработки искомого алгоритма